# Why is just my wife had been bitten by bed bugs?

Tags: hotels, bed-bugs

My wife and I are travelling for a few months. Several times my wife waked up explaining that she has been bitten by bed bugs, but I don't feel that I have been bitten.
Why is my wife their only target?
Or I have been beaten but I am not "allergic" to them?

Comment: Explaining? If it's bed bugs, there's usually evidence such as a string of small bites with coagulated blood. Unlike mosquitoes, they tend to bite multiple times in close proximity, or so I was told when I woke up like that in Slovenia. [See Google Image Search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=bed+bug+bites&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFncfbtvbKAhUIbR4KHRnLA6IQ_AUIBygB&biw=1477&bih=1300)

Comment: Maybe your wife wants to stay in a better class of accommodation and those places creep her out Source: personal experience.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about the mechanics of bed bugs.

Comment: As bedbugs are found in hotels of all classes, going to more expensive hotels might not be the solution.

Comment: Please note that you can find some products under the form of a tablet that will kill them all in just few hours. Won't make any advertisement here but you'll find them easily on the net.

Comment: Almost certainly you *are* being bitten but don't react. Not everyone reacts to the bites. I have a massive allergy to them, but there's no visible mark except the swelling. Some people can have bed bugs for months and not even notice (until someone like me visits and swells up...)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Bed bugs are not usually target specific, if they are in a bed they bite anyone in that bed.  The same applies for other non flying blood suckers like fleas, chiggers, ticks.

Flying blood suckers like mosquitoes, horse flies can be target specific zeroing in on certain people while ignoring folks sleeping right next to them.

Bed bug bites are rather easy to identify visually, follow the link in the comments above.  Bed bug bites also tend not to be felt until you wake in the morning and start scratching them.  If your wife is waking up during the night from being bit, mosquitoes are a more likely culprit.

Comment: Some people react very quickly to bed bug bites. For example, for me, they swell up, become painful and itch within about 15 seconds - quickly enough that I can sometimes catch the buggers red-handed. But plenty of people I know never react at all

Comment: @user568458 - One has to ask where you sleep to have that many experiences with bed bugs ;-)

Comment: Shared flats in London (Elephant and Castle area in particular is where I discovered my allergy - there are streets where pest companies won't even bother coming because you'll just get re-infested from neighbours! I moved out ASAP...), and hotels in Sierra Leone